# SUM statement makes system return only one column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a playerInfo table like this :

[image]

Then when i do like image below, everything is fine

[image]

Then when i try to add a SUM column to the result, Mysql return only 1 record

[image]

Why is it? What i need to do to make it display all record (2 in this case).

Comment: Please submit the raw text of your query rather than a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT *, SUM(_league) 
FROM playerInfo 
WHERE _clan IN (SELECT _name FROM clanInfo)
GROUP BY _username
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sonething like this:

```
SELECT *, SUM(_league) OVER (PARTITION BY _username)
FROM playerInfo 
WHERE _clan IN (SELECT _name FROM clanInfo)
```

This query show all rows from playerInfo table (where _clan in clanInfo table) and apply aggregation function fot each _username in additional column.